# Problem with messuring capacitance with 50 Arduinos connected by I²C

Tags: i2c, capacitors

I want to measure changes in capacitance over time. One Arduino is used per capacitance sensor. There is one anode per Arduino and a total of one common cathode (see the picture)

With four Arduinos connected in series via an I²C master-slave connection, successful results were obtained.
With more than four Arduinos, all measurement results were 0, because no voltage is measured at the input pin anymore.

I then lowered the reference voltage for analogRead. So 10 Arduinos in series were possible. However, the measured values are clearly lower. However, no absolute values are to be measured, but any difference in the capacitance is sufficient. Finally 50 Arduinos should be used.

I have thought of the following possibilities:

1. reduce the reference voltage further, but this may reduce the measurement results further, so that no deflection is measured.
2. increase the output voltage at the Arduino via an operational amplifier to compensate the voltage drop.

How could I proceed to get a usable result with all 50 Arduinos? The code I used is to be found below.

[image]

[image]

#### Master

```
#include <Wire.h>

volatile byte x1, x2;
volatile int val_slave;

const int OUT_PIN = A0;
const int IN_PIN = A2;


#define nodeMax 10
#define nodeStart 2


void setup() {
  analogReference(DEFAULT);
  Wire.begin();

  pinMode(OUT_PIN,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN_PIN,OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

  void loop() {
    
    pinMode(IN_PIN,INPUT);
    digitalWrite(OUT_PIN,HIGH);

    int val = analogRead(IN_PIN);

    digitalWrite(OUT_PIN,LOW);
    pinMode(IN_PIN,OUTPUT);

    
    Serial.print(val);
    Serial.print(",");
  
      delay(10);
      
    for (int node = nodeStart; node <= nodeMax; node++) {

        // Ask the slave to release the input pin.
        Wire.beginTransmission(node);
        Wire.write(0);
        Wire.endTransmission();
        delay(10);  // give it time to do so

        // Charge the capacitors.
        digitalWrite(OUT_PIN, HIGH);

        // Ask the slave to read val.
        Wire.requestFrom(node, sizeof(val));

        // Discharge.
        x1 = Wire.read();
    x2 = Wire.read();

    val_salve = (int)x1 << 8 | (int)x2;

        Serial.print(val_slave);
        Serial.print(",");
        
        digitalWrite(OUT_PIN, LOW);
        delay(10);
     
    }
    Serial.println();
    delay(50);
}
```

#### Slave

```
const int IN_PIN=A2;


#include <Wire.h>
#define node 10



void setup() {
    // ...
    analogReference(DEFAULT);
    Wire.begin(node);
    Serial.begin(9600);

    pinMode(IN_PIN,OUTPUT);
    
    Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
    Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
 
}



// Release IN_PIN when the master sends a message.
void receiveEvent(int byte_count) {
    pinMode(IN_PIN, INPUT);
    while (byte_count--)
        Wire.read();  // discard the received message
}

void loop ()
{
}

void requestEvent() {
    int val = analogRead(IN_PIN);
    // transmit the result... then

    
  
    Wire.write(highByte(val));
    Wire.write(lowByte(val));

    pinMode(IN_PIN, OUTPUT);  // discharge
}
```

Comment: You will need to massively reduce the pullup resistors on your I2C bus to counteract the increased gate capacitance of the number of devices. The more devices you have the lower the pullup resistors. After a while it becomes impractical to reduce the pullup resistors any more and you hit a limit on how many devices you can have on the bus. I would say 50 devices is far more than any sensible bus could cope with.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using 50 Arduinos rather than 4 Arduinos connected to 8-port multiplexers? That would reduce cost and also avoid your problem.

Comment: "Finally 50 Arduinos should be used" - why? Isn't this creating the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

The cathode line is being shared by all the Arduinos' `OUT_PIN`. When
one of them tries to set the pin `HIGH`, all the others are trying to
hold it `LOW`. This is a short-circuit condition that can damage the
Arduino's outputs. Even if they do survive, the voltage on the line will
be significantly below 5 V because of those Arduinos pulling the
line `LOW`. The more of them pull the line `LOW`, the lower the voltage
will be.

The simple solution would be to change the protocol such that only the
Arduino that is currently making a measurement can pull that line, while
the others keep their `OUT_PIN` in high-impedance mode (i.e. `INPUT`).
This is fragile because... bugs happen, and you may still be making a
short-circuit. A more robust solution would be to connect *only* the
master to the cathode, and give it the responsibility to drive the line
`HIGH` and `LOW`.

Now, a coupe of unrelated comments:

- A `float` is four bytes: there is no point in transmitting ten bytes.
- You can measure up to four capacitors with each Arduino (pins `A0`
  through `A3`, you can use a digital pin for `OUT_PIN`), it is wasteful
  to use one Arduino per capacitor.

**Edit**: If only the master controls `OUT_PIN`, then some communication
protocol is needed in order to synchronize it with the slaves, so that
they can release `IN_PIN` at the right time. The simplest protocol I can
think of is the following: when the master sends something (*anything*)
to a slave, this message means “please release `IN_PIN` now”.

Here is some untested code implementing this idea:

**master**:

```cpp
void loop() {
    // ...
    for (int node = nodeStart; node <= nodeMax; node++) {

        // Ask the slave to release the input pin.
        Wire.beginTransmission(node);
        Wrire.write(0);
        Wire.endTransmission();
        delay(10);  // give it time to do so

        // Charge the capacitors.
        digitalWrite(OUT_PIN, HIGH);

        // Ask the slave to read the capacitance.
        Wire.requestFrom(node, sizeof(capacitanceSlave));

        // Discharge.
        digitalWrite(OUT_PIN, LOW);

        // ...
    }
}
```

**slave**:

```cpp
void setup() {
    // ...
    Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
    Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
}

// Release IN_PIN when the master sends a message.
void receiveEvent(int byte_count) {
    pinMode(IN_PIN, INPUT);
    while (byte_count--)
        Wire.read();  // discard the received message
}

void requestEvent() {
    int val = analogRead(IN_PIN);
    // transmit the result... then
    pinMode(IN_PIN, OUTPUT);  // discharge
}
```

Comment: In an I2C configuration no-one sets the output high. The pull-up resistors do that.

Comment: @NickGammon: I am talking about the line labeled “cathode” in the drawing, not about the I2C SDA.

Comment: OK. The "circuit diagram" wasn't all that clear.

Comment: @Eggar Bonet: First of all thanks for the answeres,
i tried your suggestion by only connecting the master to the cathode and changing the code, but it didnt work. the sensor conected to the master gives a way better capacitance output, but the slaves output is "nan".
I have to use one arduino per Sensor because in previouse scientific works two sensors interferre on one Arduino and the results are bad.

Comment: @Imogdia: There must be something wrong with either your updated circuit or your updated code. You may want to update the question in order for it to reflect the current circuit and code.

Comment: @Imogdia: With the updated code, the slaves are still pulling down on `OUT_PIN`. And they release `IN_PIN` _after_ the master has set `OUT_PIN` to `HIGH`, which is too late. You need a more elaborate communication protocol, where the master tells the slave when to release `IN_PIN`.

Comment: And how do I can do this?
Im totally new to arduinos and i have no programming experience

Comment: @Imogdia: See expanded answer.

Comment: I´ve tested your code (see updated threat), but the outcome is still the same.
i´ve tested your code on 10 arduinos and the results are these:
only the master gets a messurement

12:22:21.472 -> 1.38,45,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,
12:22:21.710 -> 1.38,45,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,
12:22:21.947 -> 1.41,46,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,
12:22:22.186 -> 1.38,45,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,
12:22:22.426 -> 1.38,45,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,
12:22:22.700 -> 1.38,45,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,

Comment: @Tizian: 1. Your slaves are still driving `OUT_PIN`. 2. They are not sending anything (my comment `// transmit the result...` was meant to be replaced by your result-transmitting code). 3. Why call `Wire.onRequest()` twice? 4. Try sending a fixed value (e.g. `12.34`) to rule out a communication problem. 5. Why not send the raw ADC reading instead of the computed capacitance?

Comment: @EdgarBonet I´ve updated my code again. Thanks for your help! im gonna test it tomorrow and can tell you if it worked.

Comment: @EdgarBonet It worked perfectly, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The I²C bus was never intended as a distribution bus between many computers. The outputs are not designed to drive long wires. With a lot of kludging you may get this to work, but it is definitely not repeatable or reliable.

Consider something else. [CAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus) can do maybe 60 nodes, depending on the transceiver chosen. It is relatively inexpensive.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using a RS485 protocol. Unlike I2C this uses "balanced" wiring so is more suitable for longer cable runs.

I described a way of coding a number of Arduinos using a "rolling master" protocol [here](https://gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11428) - this lets you connect a considerable number of Arduinos to the two wires, and they take turns to send the data.

However in your case, since you are measuring capacitance (not capacity?) then each of your Arduinos can measure 6 (or possibly more) analog readings, so you don't need 50, you need 50/6 = 8.33 Arduinos (OK, nine).

The [Arduino Micro](https://store-usa.arduino.cc/products/arduino-micro?selectedStore=us), for example, has 12 analog input channels, so you would only need 4 (to get 48 inputs) or 5 (to get 60 inputs). Then you could stick to I2C.

Comment: I recommended CAN because of the 50 nodes, RS485 has a limit of 32. To extend beyond that repeaters are needed.